# ApparelSizeVariantProductModel cannot be resolved to a type in Hybris

Tags: model, sap-commerce-cloud

While working on a b2c extension myb2ccore,I deleted the Hybris provided itemtypes like `ApparelSizeVariantProduct` because they were not required as a part of my code.However,now I am getting an error:

`ApparelSizeVariantProductModel cannot be resolved to a type` as there is some Hybris code which depends on this.How to resolve this error and if I am right to remove this itemtype and associated itemtypes provided by Hybris in my extension if I do not require them?

Answer (score 1):

Re-reading your question gives me an idea about the real problem in this case.

*Let's talk about the Hybris `itemtypes` :*

When we initializ the Database, we translate `items.xml` files into a Database structure (that means create tables, columns, indexs ...), in the same time, we store types in a specific structure, the same when we add a new itemtype to `items.xml` followed by `update system`.

**Problem :**

When removing an `itemtype` from `items.xml` dose not mean that this type will be removed from your Database structure or even the stored type in the DB and that is your problem in this case.

**Solution :**

To resolve this kind of problems, you need to :

- Rebuild your sources using the following command : `ant clean all`
- Lunch a new `update system` on your server.
- Open the HAC interface, go to `Maintenance->Cleanup`. Ensure both check boxes are selected and click the `Clear all orphaned types` button in *Type system* tab.

*For the second question :*

> You should not, in any case, remove an Hybris native type. You can do
> it only for your custom types.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your answer.Actually after generating a b2c extension,it contained the boilerplate Hybris code.So I was asking whether I can remove that from myb2ccore-items.xml

Comment: You are welcom! You can mark the answer as a solution, that gonna help other people to resolve same problems.